# Solving for the phase shift of a neutron due to precession in magnetic field

Tags: quantum-mechanics, interference

In the famous experiment that was used to prove the sign change of the wave function due to a rotation of 2$\pi$ by Werner et al. It is stated directly that the phase shift of the neutron beam is equal to $2\pi g_{n} \mu_n M \lambda B l / h^2$ Where l is the length of the region within the magnetic field, $g_n$ is the neutron magnetic moment, and $\mu_n$ is the nuclear magneton.

I am trying to show this for myself but I am having quite a bit of trouble picking up many of the terms they have. I am starting with the same trick they use to "rotate" their neutrons. We know a stationary neutron in a magnetic field has a hamiltonian = $-\mu B$. The time evolution operator is as follows $U(t,0) = e^{-iHt/\hbar}$ and the rotation operator $D_s(\phi) = e^{-i S_s \phi /\hbar}$. If we actually work out our hamiltonian and plug it into our time evolution operator we get $U(t,0) = e^{-i( 2 g_n \mu_n S_s t B) /\hbar^2 }$ its clear that this is the same as the rotation operator if we pick $\phi$ to be $\frac{2 g_n \mu_n S_s t B}{\hbar}$.

From here I am stuck. I'm not sure how to correctly extract a statement on the phase from what I have. And I assume I will pick up some of their terms when I sub in for t in terms of the variables at hand, yet I don't see how I will get their exact solution. Any advice onw here to go from here would be much appreciated, here is a link to the paper, http://www.rpi.edu/dept/phys/courses/PHYS6510/PhysRevLett.35.1053.pdf . Any additional information needed is on the first page.